# Regex inside HAProxy configuration to match any character

Tags: regex, haproxy

I want to redirect a certain type of URLs 301 if they are not on https to http. The syntax of the regex somehow does not work:

```
redirect scheme https code 301 if { hdr(Host) -i ^project-.*$ } !{ ssl_fc }
```

it should match project-de, project-us, etc..

Without regex the line works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-m` modificator: `if { hdr(Host) -m reg -i ^project-.*$ }` or `if { hdr(Host) -m beg -i project- }`